# position div with auto width left of screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Note: this css in snippet does not exactly equal my setup (I have fixed div in body) but otherwise its the same effect. I have div with auto width (text inside), which opens from the left. I want to close it such that it animates to left to its full width minus 50px. This works well when screen width is bigger then element width, but when its smaller, my element is already squished, so when I do calculation on button click, the width is not correct and when I animate out, it doesn't get to desired position (because it expand to its natural width as it gets more space going to the left).

How do I solve this?

```js
var b = $('.b')

document.querySelector('#toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {



  var w = b.outerWidth(true),
    pos = w - 50
  console.log(w)

  b.stop().animate({
    'left': -pos + 'px'
  }, {
    duration: 350
  });

})
```

```css
.a {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.b {
  background: #ddd;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">

    <div class="t">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="t">Ut laoreet hendrerit mi.</div>
    <div class="t">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="toggle">toggle</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use jQuery
- Use CSS and `transform` `translate`, and `transition` for the desired animation
- Use JavaScript to [Element.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) a desired CSS class — that will transition the element from left -100% (of its own width) to left 0%.
- use a `<button type="button">` if you actually need a button. Anchors are for something else (Navigation).

```js
const EL = (sel, par) => (par||document).querySelector(sel);

EL("#toggle").addEventListener("click", () => {
  EL("#menu").classList.toggle("is-open");
});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  /* hopefully you know how to style a Button */
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 30px;
  width: calc(100vw - 100px); /* or whatever you want, does not matters */
  height: 100vh;
  background: gold;
  transition: transform 0.5s; /* transition property and duration */
  transform: translateX(-100%); /* -100% of self-width (hidden) */
}

#menu.is-open {
  transform: translateX(0%); /* (visible) */
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">I am something that actually toggles</div>

<button type="button" id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't what I need. I though it was clear from the demo and my description. It needs to animate out to its full width minus 50px. The element does NOT  have a fixed width.  And if its natural width is wider than the parent body, as it animates out, it expands so I cannot calculate left correctly. In my demo imagine '.a' is the body element.

Comment: @Toniq you do NOT need a fixed width and the above will STILL work. It's even mentioned in the CSS comment: *"or whatever you want, does not matters"*. And I cannot imagine `.a` being `body` since the toggle button would be placed outside of body in that case :)

Comment: But how do I make it close its full width minus 50px (so it sticks out 50px when closed), that was my question?  Edit: I found it: transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 50px));

Comment: @Toniq exactly, calc() is your friend here for any dynamic + known things.